# MPMoviePlayerController custom airplay button

Tags: ios, mpmovieplayercontroller, airplay

I have a MPMoviePlayerController with custom controls. I wanted to add a Button to this custom view that would send the video via AirPlay. Is this possible? i have read the apple documentation on MPMoviePlayerController but did not found anything on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved it with this:

```
MPVolumeView *volumeView = [ [MPVolumeView alloc] init] ;
[volumeView setRouteButtonImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ICAirPlay"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[volumeView sizeToFit];
```